# How do I debug javascript errors like this?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and was trying to figure out why the following code was not working:

```
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org/");
ws.onmessage = msg => console.log(msg);
let queue = [];
ws.onopen = () => {
    queue.forEach(msg => ws.send(msg));
};

const send = () => {
    if(ws.readyState === ws.OPEN){
        ws.send(msg);
    }
    else{
      queue.push(msg);
    }
};

send("foo");
send("bar");
```

Then I realized that I needed: `let send = (msg) => {`.

Before finding the problem, I had used lint and dev tools but I cdidn't see any warnings. What should I be doing to find there kinds of problems?

http://www.es6fiddle.net/iu3qwem6/

Comment: Don't you have a "*ReferenceError: msg is not defined*" error ?

Comment: @No I don't see this warning. I am using Firefox 49.0.1. Should I be using something else?

Comment: I'm on 50.0b3, and when I copy paste your code in ES6Fiddle, I got the error coming from babel.js

Comment: @Kaiido If I run http://www.es6fiddle.net/iu3r5ofj/ I see nothing in the devtools console window. I am logging Errors, Warnings, Info, Log.

Comment: just tried in an old FF38, in an FF47 and in latest stable 49.0.1 and I always have the message...

Comment: @Kaiido Installed Chrome and I do get the message there. I'm using Mac OS 10.12.

Comment: I'm on 10.9, but that should not matter. It looks like a really strange bug in your FF config.

Answer (score 0):

eslint. There's even a specific rule for this one: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

You should probably get a ReferenceError, because your let/const implies strict syntax, though if you missed that I'm guessing your engine wasn't picking up on strict mode for whatever reason. It's a better error to find with static analysis anyway, because it will pick up the error even if the function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you give TypeScript a try. Have a look at your example at [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20ws%20%3D%20new%20WebSocket(%22ws%3A%2F%2Fecho.websocket.org%2F%22)%3B%0D%0Aws.onmessage%20%3D%20msg%20%3D%3E%20console.log(msg)%3B%0D%0Alet%20queue%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Aws.onopen%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20queue.forEach(msg%20%3D%3E%20ws.send(msg))%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20send%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(ws.readyState%20%3D%3D%3D%20ws.OPEN)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ws.send(msg)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20queue.push(msg)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Asend(%22foo%22)%3B%0D%0Asend(%22bar%22)%3B).

It will immediatelly tell you: `Cannot find name msg` inside your `send` function.